# Boot Failure on Ubuntu 22.04.3 After Attempting to Install Radeon™ Software for AMD RX 6800xt

Tags: drivers, 22.04, amdgpu

I'm experiencing boot issues with Ubuntu 22.04.3 after attempting to install the Radeon™ Software for my AMD RX 6800xt. Here are the steps I took and the problems I encountered:

**Initial Installation Attempt:** I downloaded Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 23.30 for Ubuntu 22.04.3 from the AMD website and installed the .deb file using apt. When I tried running `sudo amdgpu-install -y`, I received the following error:

```
Errors found while processing:
amdgpu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Uninstalling Software:** Not wanting to troubleshoot further at the time, I ran `amdgpu-uninstall -y`. However, after rebooting, my PC failed to boot, displaying an error followed by a white screen. The error message was:

```
=================================================================================
UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/rt18188fu/4.3.26.6~ppa/build/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:5751:19
shift exponent 131072 is too large dor 32-bit type 'int'
=================================================================================
```

**Troubleshooting Attempts:** I have CLI access through safe mode with GRUB. I've tried the following commands to completely remove amdgpu-install and clean up:

```
apt purge -y amdgpu-install
apt update
apt upgrade
apt clean
apt autoclean
dpkg --configure -a
```

Unfortunately, these steps have not resolved the issue.

**Question:** How can I rescue my operating system and resolve these boot issues? Are there specific steps I should follow to correctly install or remove the AMD drivers?

**Updates:**

1. When running `sudo update-initramfs -k all -c`I get this error a lot of times

   ```
   libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:712 kmod_config_parse:
   /etc/modprobe.d/rt18188fu.conf line 1:ignoring bad line starting with '"opions'
   ```
2. `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rt18188fu.conf`

   ```
   "options rt18188fu rtw_ips_mode=0"
   ```

Comment: I might try `man mkinitramfs` and `sudo update-initramfs -k all -c`